# Using strings to store scores for a python maths quiz

Tags: python, file, math

The scores for the maths quiz need to be arranged:

-alphabetically by name with the high score
-by the highest score highest to lowest
-by the average score highest to lowest
If possible I would like to use strings to do this and if you could show me how to do this I would be grateful. I am thinking about using strings but I don't know how you'd do this.
The code i have so far is:

```
import random
def start_quiz():
    print("Welcome to my Maths quiz")
#this creates a subroutine to enter the users name
def get_name():
    global name
    global group

    name=input("What is your name?")
    while name=="":
          name=input("What is your name?")
          group=input("What class are you in-1,2 or 3?")
    while group=="":
          group=input("What class are you in?")
    print("Hello " + name)

def questions():
    global score
    global questionnumber
    score=0
    questionnumber=0
    while questionnumber<10:
        questionnumber=questionnumber+1 
        operatorlist=['+','-','*']
        num1=random.randint(1,10)
        num2=random.randint(1,10)
        op=random.choice(operatorlist)
        if op=='-' and num2>num1:
            expression="%d %s %d" % (num2,op,num1)
        else:
            expression="%d %s %d" % (num1,op,num2)
        answer=eval(expression)
        enter_answer=1
        while enter_answer==1:
            try:
                useranswer= int(input(expression))
                enter_answer=0
            except ValueError:
                print("that was not a number, please re enter your answer")
        answer=int(answer)
        if useranswer==answer:
            print("well done")
            score=score+1
            print(" ")
        else:
            print("incorrect the correct answer is %d " % (answer))




def end_quiz():
    print("The quiz is now over")
    print("Well done " + name+". Your score is %d out of 10" % (score))

def savethescore():
    global score
    score=str(score)
    if group=='1':
        file=open("Scoreforclass1.txt",'a')
        file.write("\n")
        file.write ("Name: "+name+"\n")
        file.write('Class: '+group+'\n')
        file.write("Score: "+score+"/10\n")
        file.close()
    elif group=='2':
        file=open("Scoreforclass2.txt",'a')
        file.write("\n")
        file.write ("Name: "+name+"\n")
        file.write('Class: '+group+'\n')
        file.write("Score: "+score+"/10\n")
        file.close()
    else:
        file=open("Scoreforclass3.txt",'a')
        file.write("\n")
        file.write ("Name: "+name+"\n")
        file.write('Class: '+group+'\n')
        file.write("Score: "+score+"/10\n")
        file.close()


 def play_again():
     again= input("would you like to play again? y for yes and n for no")
     while again not in ['Y','y','N','n']:
         again = input("please enter 'Y' or 'N'")
     if again== 'y' or 'Y':
        do_the_quiz()
     else:
         print("cheers lad thanks for playing")
         exit()


def do_the_quiz():
    start_quiz()
    get_name()
    questions()
    end_quiz()
    savethescore()
    play_again()

do_the_quiz()
```

If possible can you try to use strings as I tried using csv files but it got too complicated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: To try and use text files to do the 3 things at the start of the question

Comment: "*if you could create code to do this*" is not a valid question. Please show how you have attempted to solve the problem, even if it's just describing in words how you think it should be done. What steps, in order, would you need to follow to allow you to do what you're trying to do? You'll need to use some strings, yes, but you'll also need numbers to calculate rank and averages. Where will your data come from? Where will it go once it has been calculated? Think about all this, then translate it into Python. If you then have a **specific** question about that code, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
import re
from functools import reduce

data=""
try:
    data+=open("Scoreforclass1.txt","r").read()
except:
    pass
try:
    data+=open("Scoreforclass2.txt","r").read()
except:
    pass
try:
    data+=open("Scoreforclass3.txt","r").read()
except:
    pass
allscores_name={}
allscores_score={}
averagescore_score={}

pattern=re.compile("Name: [^\n]*?\nClass: [^\n]*?\nScore: [^\n]*?\n")
data=pattern.findall(data)
for line in data:
    start=line.find("Name: ")+len("Name: ")
    end=line.find("\n",start)
    name=line[start:end].strip()
    start=line.find("Class: ",end)+len("Class: ")
    end=line.find("\n",start)
    classnum=line[start:end].strip()
    start=line.find("Score: ",end)+len("Score: ")
    end=line.find("/10\n",start)
    score=line[start:end].strip()
    if(name+classnum in allscores_name):
        allscores_name[name+classnum].append(int(score))
    else:
        allscores_name[name+classnum]=[int(score)]
    if(int(score) in allscores_score):
        allscores_score[int(score)].append(name+classnum)
    else:
        allscores_score[int(score)]=[name+classnum]

out=open("sortedbyname.txt",'w+')
for name in sorted(allscores_name.keys()):
    average=reduce(lambda x, y: x + y,map(int,allscores_name[name])) / float(len(allscores_name[name]))
    if(average in averagescore_score):
        averagescore_score[average].append(name)
    else:
        averagescore_score[average]=[name]
    for score in sorted(allscores_name[name]):
        out.write("\n")
        out.write ("Name: "+name[:-1]+"\n")
        out.write('Class: '+name[-1]+'\n')
        out.write("Score: "+str(score)+"/10\n")
out.close()

out=open("sortedbyscore.txt",'w+')
for score in sorted(allscores_score.keys())[::-1]:
    for name in sorted(allscores_score[score]):
        out.write("\n")
        out.write ("Name: "+name[:-1]+"\n")
        out.write('Class: '+name[-1]+'\n')
        out.write("Score: "+str(score)+"/10\n")
out.close()

out=open("sortedbyaverage.txt",'w+')
for avgscore in sorted(averagescore_score.keys())[::-1]:
    out.write("\n")
    out.write ("Name: "+name[:-1]+"\n")
    out.write('Class: '+name[-1]+'\n')
    for name in sorted(averagescore_score[avgscore]):
        for score in sorted(allscores_name[name])[::-1]:
            out.write("Score: "+str(score)+"/10\n")
out.close()
```

Cheers!

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'

Comment: If you are using Python 3, you can change the iterkeys() to keys(). iterkeys() lost support in Python 3. I have edited my answer.

Comment: it doesnt work, it doesnt write names and scores in the 3 newly created text files

Comment: it says reduce is not defined?

Comment: It now works with Python 3.4. reduce() was moved to functools.reduce() as indicated by the second import at the top. If it works for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: is that just clicking the tick?